# How does one know what built-in methods exist in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a list with all the built in methods? When I have a problem someone will say something like "ruby has a built in method for that"... Well how would one know that?

Comment: The usual reference book is http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby

Answer (score 5):

You can check the [Ruby Standard Library API](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/) or the [Core API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/) (scroll down a bit).

Both are extremely useful, especially the Core API.

For example, if you're wondering what things standard arrays can do see: [The Ruby Core page On `Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html)

Happy coding!

Comment: In Ruby, everything is an object. Everything. There are no "global" methods that don't come from some object. `Kernel ` probably has most of the methods you are wondering about. In an empty file, ruby creates an `Object` called main that all your code runs from. Try reflexive methods like: `public_methods, methods, self.class, self.class.ancestors` to discover where you are and what is available. There is also the method `method` (e.g. `method :puts`) that grabs a method so you can learn who defines it and possibly the `.source_location` if it's not a native method.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this

```
ClassName.method
ObjectName.method
Integer.methods
Integer.class.methods
```

so you can do what evert you have `.methods` and see what comes back its really simple

Comment: Let's not forget `.singleton_methods`.  Also, I generally tack on `.sort` or `include?(method_name)`.

Comment: I often use `<ClassName>.methods.sort - Object.methods` to get methods specific to ClassName.

Comment: `Kernel.methods.sort` returns all the builtin methods that don't seem to belong to any class.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassName.methods #=> returns all methods
ClassName.public_methods #=> returns all public methods
ClassName.private_methods #=> returns all private methods
```

e.g

```
String.methods
String.public_methods
String.private_methods
String.singleton_methods
```

You may wan't to remove all the Object methods

```
   String.methods - Object.methods
```