# Generate a random token in ruby >= 2.5.1 / >= rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30709867/5783745) that `has_secure_token` can generate a random token for a new record in a (User) model. How can I simply generate a random token without needing to do it for a model? (i.e. suppose an app *has no model(s)* or to put it really simply, to run some (preferably very simple) method, and it should return a random string like `pX27zsMN2ViQKta1bGfLmVJE`

I have tried gems [SecureRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893073/howto-generate-random-token-in-ruby) and [digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377748/how-to-generate-a-unique-random-id-for-post-in-ruby-on-rails-4) as recommended in other answers, but neither seems to bundle install successfully (the SO answers were oldish so perhaps those gems are deprecated?) - I'm using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2.3

My goal is simply to generate tokens to use as keys for an API, so I essentially just need randomly generated strings that are safe to use in urls, perhaps a method that I can specify the length of the token (but I'll take what I can get for now!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `SecureRandom`. It's not a gem that you have to install. It's built into Ruby:

```
⇒ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
⇒ irb
2.5.1 :001 > require 'securerandom'
 => true
2.5.1 :002 > SecureRandom.hex(32)
 => "89d45edb28859a905672b707c8f7599f766d12074584ef48a997230dfc0e0998"
2.5.1 :003 > SecureRandom.base64(12)
 => "KaZbhQ7o7U/f9pMs"
2.5.1 :004 > SecureRandom.uuid
 => "ade17ef5-0943-4c70-b417-df7c96c198cd"
```

Comment: For future reference, how can you tell which gems you have to install and which come built in?

Comment: Lots of different ways. You can check the [standard library API](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/), the [core API](https://ruby-doc.org/core), and also [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/). You can look at external resources like [this](https://ruby.fandom.com/wiki/Built-in_classes) and [this](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/builtins.html), but I don't know if they're up to date. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19151296/3784008).